# "Aviaflight mode": Wifi blocked

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, lenovo

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo B560. Core Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae

I have set Wifi switcher "on" and Driver Broadcom STA "on".

Window "Network" --> "Aviaflight mode" isn't switched off. I added "blacklist acer_wmi" in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

WiFi doesn't work. (rfkill list: Hard blocked: yes).

How to switch off "Aviaflight mode" in Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

What is the position of switch #1 here? Does Fn+F5 change anything? What is the entirety of:

```
rfkill list all
```

[image]

Comment: rfkill list:
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes


switch #1 - "on". Fn+F5 - no reaction.
The problem appeared after updating (only official 12.04). 
Problem options: new kernel 3.2.0-34 (?) or the mode of air flights (is always included and blocks wireless).

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB prompt and boot into an earlier kernel? Was acer-wmi loaded when you first installed? Did blacklisting it help in earlier kernels? I believe 'flight mode' is immovable if the wireless radio is hard-blocked by the hardware switch or at least if the operating system thinks it is.